# Can't add pygame to pycharm?

Tags: pygame, pycharm

Could someone help me with adding pygame to pycharm, I've tried going to pycharm setting and installing pygame in the project interpreter where the + sign is

[Me going to setting and project interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv82L.png)

[Me going to install pygame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6SGL.png)

But when installing this error appears

[Me installing but the error occurs once done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRfgT.png)

[More details on the error that occur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzE8o.png)

I've tried going to the command prompt and installing pygame there

[This is what I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfp5x.jpg)

But this error occurs

[This error always occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiiON.png)

I've tried looking at my environmental variable and followed a video, to see if my path is correct, which it is. Checked that I've updated pip and that tried running the command prompt both as an administrator and not. And even tried to uninstall and install different versions of python. 
At this point I need help? If anyone could help, I would be truly grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, IF you're using python 3.8.0, python for whatever reason not allow you to install pygame or for any other package, in fact, you'll get the errors I got above in my question. The way to fix this is that you must uninstall python 3.8.0 and install an older version (I installed Python 3.7.5), this worked for me and allowed me to download pygame. I have no idea why you can't install packages in 3.8.0 might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while ago too, you could try installing pygame through pycharm's virtual terminal. Pycharm's virtual terminal is located at the bottom of the screen. To open it, the button is on the bottom left next to the Python Console and to-do list. Inside pycharm's virtual terminal you should input,

```
pip install pygame
```

After this, you should be able to import pygame with ease. Hope this helps! Make sure to mark my answer as correct if it helps you out. Have a good day.

Comment: Hello @PaulMcBurney, thank you for responding to my question, however, unfortunately, it did not work when I tried it in the **Pycharm's virtual terminal** and gave me the same error labeled _This error always occurs_ as seen above.